# Get Discord PY Objects In JSON

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Is there a way to get a discord py object in JSON? For example, if I have a message object is it possible to have discord.py return it as a dictionary so that I can pass it to javascript later?

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  # what usually happens
  print(message.content)
  # what I want
  print(message['content'])
  # {'author': {'id': 0, 'avatar': '', ...}, ...}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to make a dict out of the message information yourself and then dump it to a JSON format?

Comment: That's what i'm trying to avoid doing...

Comment: @Walker, "is it possible to have discord.py return it as a dictionary": I don't think there's a discord.py function for that. See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message. As @Dominik said, I guess you have to create a dictionary yourself. Use a `for` loop to get all attributes of the `Message` and set the value as a dictionary?

Comment: @Walker, try to code it yourself, and if you have any issues with the code, feel free to [edit] the question (probably avoid a new question for this).

Comment: The problem with using loops and getAttr is because of the nested objects like message.author and such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. All I had to do was turn the variables into JSON

```py
json.loads(vars(message))
```

Comment: The description here is backwards: [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.loads) takes JSON as an _input_ and returns a Python data structure.